# difference between chrome.runtime.onmessage and chrome.runtime.port onmessage event

Tags: google-chrome-extension

My below contentscript.js receives the message only to chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener but not to port.onMessage.addListener

```
             console.log("loaded");
              var port = chrome.runtime.connect({name: "knockknock"});
              port.postMessage({joke: "Knock knock"});
              port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
              port.postMessage({answer: "Madame... Bovary"});
              });
              chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, response) {
              console.log("cs:on message ");
              });

I send the following message from my backgroundscript.js:



             chrome.tabs.query({
                  active: true,
                  currentWindow: true
              }, function(tabs) {
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
                  console.log("message sent");
                });
              });
```

Why doesn't my port.onMessage.addListener not triggered though its initialized.

Answer (score 0):

From https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging :

> In order to handle incoming connections, you need to set up a
>   runtime.onConnect event listener. This looks the same from a content
>   script or an extension page. When another part of your extension calls
>   "connect()", this event is fired, along with the runtime.Port object
>   you can use to send and receive messages through the connection.
>   Here's what it looks like to respond to incoming connections:

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
  console.assert(port.name == "knockknock");
  port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
    if (msg.joke == "Knock knock")
      port.postMessage({question: "Who's there?"});
    else if (msg.answer == "Madame")
      port.postMessage({question: "Madame who?"});
    else if (msg.answer == "Madame... Bovary")
      port.postMessage({question: "I don't get it."});
  });
});
```

So this is how you would catch your message from the specific port:

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
  port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
    console.log(msg) // msg object will be your message
  })
})
```